# Как сделать ввывод буквы "б" на pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Хотел сделать функцию,которая переведет строку на русском в английскую раскладку клавиатуры возникла проблема с буквой "б".

```py
def rusineng(t):
    t=list(t)
    global answer
    answer=str()
    for i in t:
        rus=str("АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя")
        eng=str('F<DULT~:PBQRKVYJGHCNEA{WXIO}SM">Zf⚙dult`;[bqrkvyjghcnea[wxio]sm')
        eng2=str("'.z")
        eng3=eng+eng2
        rus=list(rus)
        eng=list(eng3)
        element=rus.index(i)
        element=eng.pop(element)
        answer+=element
    return answer
```

Вот мой код.

Но что поставить место шестеренки?

Comment: Покажите пример или подробнее опишите Вашу проблему.

Comment: Какая проблема?

Comment: к примеру мне надо перевести слова "да" функцая должна вернуть "lf" а как перевести слово "булочка" то она вернет ",ekjxrf" но в итоге это слово будет переведено как ",улочка" f vyt yflj ,ekjxrf

Comment: https://pianowow.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/russian-to-english/

Comment: @Валентит ну правьте свой код, который постеснялись здесь показать.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. И уберите строчку global answer.  Она не нужна. Да и t=list(t) тоже не нужна.

Comment: У меня такая проблема я перевожу слово булочка=",ekjxrf" ,если pyautogui  будет писать слово ",ekjxrf" на русской раскладке то она напишет ",улочка" ,а не булочка